# how do i get the type of change that happened in onSnapshot in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how do i get the type of change that happened in onSnapshot in firebase,
i want to use a if statement on the change to know the type of snapshot change if it was a ' add, remove, modified'

Answer (score 1):

It is explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) in the doc. The provided example is:

```
import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("state", "==", "CA"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === "added") {
        console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
    }
    if (change.type === "modified") {
        console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
    }
    if (change.type === "removed") {
        console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
    }
  });
});
```